# Pgloader change datetime from mysql to postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgloader

I tried to migrate mysql data to postgres. All works fine but when I see the datetime fields in postgres are 5 hours behind mysql. How can I do to disable whatever pgloader is doing?

Thanks

I'm using this command

```
pgloader mysql://root:root@mysql57/database1 postgresql://postgres@localhost/database2
```

Comment: This sounds like a time-zone issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. You have to create a file (could be info.load) like this:

```
LOAD DATABASE
FROM mysql://root:root@mysql57/database1
INTO postgresql://postgres@localhost/database2
CAST type datetime to timestamp drop default drop not null using zero-dates-to-null;
```

then use the command

```
pgloader info.load
```

In that way, pgloader keeps the same datetime from mysql